# Whats is better? AMD Opteron 3280, 8 Cores, 8x 2.4 GHz vs Intel Xeon X3210 Quad Core

Tags: intel, benchmark, xeon, central-processing-unit, opteron

What server is better to rent and make a hosting for large website.

IIS 7 asp.net 4 and sql server express. under windows 2008 r2 standard, and using hyper-V with linux (ubuntu), to ssh server.

AMD Opteron 3280, 8 Cores, 8x 2.4 GHz 
vs 
Intel Xeon X3210 Quad Core

Both with 8 GB RAM.

I Would like know, what the best in cpu benchmark, and others

Comment: It probably doesn't matter. Either is fine. However, there isn't enough information in your original question to help make a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too open.  The answer heavily depends on what you are doing. Just telling us which programs you are going to use is not enough.

E.g. mostly static pages with a few simple fields read from the SQL server would not require much. Which makes the cheapest CPU *the best*.     Extensive joins or complex operations might be CPU bound.  Serving lots of [large] files might be IO bound.

Given your focus on the CPU's I suspect that you already thought about it and that it will be CPU bound. It might be nice to expand on that part in your question.